# Column information cannot be retrieved error when connecting database after closing it

Tags: python, db2

I'm writing a program that passes a lot of SQL queries.The program stays open all the time, and generates queries. So I have to close the connection. However, If I don't close the connection, db2 works well and I get what I want for the number of my need. But I need to close it, and then reconnect it. This time, I am getting the below mentioned problem.

Here is the sample code for the issue:

```
import ibm_db

i=0
while i<5:
    cnnNOW = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=NOW;HOSTNAME=***;PORT=***;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=***;PWD=***;", "", "")
    sqlSlc = "SELECT <column_name> FROM <table>"
    stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(cnnNOW, sqlSlc)
    
    while ibm_db.fetch_row(stmt) != False:          #The error occurs here for the second loop
        porder = ibm_db.result(stmt, '<column_name>')
    
    ibm_db.close(cnnNOW)
    i+=1
```

Progress gives me the first result until reconnecting database. The exception is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Burhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\burhan\desktop\uzak\selectdenemesi.py", line 13, in <module>
    while ibm_db.fetch_row(stmtNOWs) != False:

Exception: Column information cannot be retrieved:
```

I'm using **Python 3.10.5** and **DB2 v10.5.0.420**. These are my setup.

Comment: There should be more information on the error, maybe a call stack.

Answer (score 0):

WThis may be a frequently asked question.

You will get

> "Column information cannot be retrieved"

when you attempt any fetch action when there is no result set, in other words - it is the expected behaviour . It is almost always a mistake in your code.

In this case, what is happening is that a query is not returning any rows for whatever reason, but your code  runs a fetch action without first checking that it is safe to do that fetch.

Either try `if stmt:` following the `exec_immediate` and place the loop inside this block for conditional execution, or better to use a single guard on the loop  e.g.

```
while stmt:
    stmt = ibm_db.fetch_row(stmt)
    ...
```

Additionally you should code `try:` and `except:` (and maybe `else:` and `finally:` blocks around any statement that might fail, including the connect and close and exec_immediate. When working with databases, assume that every statement can fail, and code defensively, recording each exception and deciding which statement to retry etc.

In such loops, also use free_result() to free up resources.

Comment: Same problem still occurs